# Import Wordpress site to localhost, but loads blank white screen

Tags: localhost

WAMP works fine on my PC.

I've created a Wordpress install on `D:/wamp/www`, replacing the default WAMP `index.php`, and I've created a new database.

I've exported the database from the remote site, replaced any instances of `www.example.com/` with `localhost/`, and imported this edited database into the db I created earlier.

I've created `/wp-config.php` and entered correct db connection details.

However `http://localhost` loads a blank white screen, with no source code.

I've set `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in `wp-config.php`, and no errors show.

There is nothing in `D:\wamp\logs\apache_error.log` indicating what the problem is.

Any idea what the problem is? Thanks.

Comment: Did you turned on [WP_DEBUG](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) on? Any errors?

Comment: please modify the wp-config.php change the define('WP_DEBUG', false); to define('WP_DEBUG', true); and check for the error.

Comment: Yep. Sorry forgot to mention, I have, and nothing shows on the front end, or Apache logs.

Comment: Did you grant permissions to the user created to access the new database?

Comment: I was using the global `root` user, but creating a dedicated user account, and granting permissions, made no change.

Comment: This seems quite specific, not sure why it was downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error.

I was creating a new WP install, importing the DB, but forgot to copy the themes into `/wp-content` !

Comment: That would make a difference! Glad it's sorted. Maybe accept your answer to round things off?

Answer (score 0):

Could replacing the default index.php be the issue? [Other posts suggest problems with that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227529/restoring-localhost-home-page-in-php-myadmin) and the [WAMP install instructions](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) talk about putting PHP files in a subdirectory.

Comment: I've upgraded from WampServer 2.4.* to 2.5, and have set up a vhost `http://mylocalhost` which loads `D:\wamp\www\mylocalhost`, and the issue remains.

Answer (score 0):

replace the links in database (wp_options) and delete .htaccess. check if you have the right theme active.